# Unit testing sql.DB/Tx calls in Go with gomock

Tags: unit-testing, go, gomock

It’s already the 3rd day I’m thinking about this problem but without any solution.
I need to **unit test** my `Tx manager` - check that in all combinations `rollback()` and `commit()` methods all called in proper sequence.

`sql.DB` has the method `BeginTx` which returns `sql.Tx`. It returns a final type, not an interface (according to Go - pass interfaces and return types).
But in this case it’s not possible to return `mock` from `BeginTx` call - because even if we return mocked `Tx-interface` it has a different type!

I tested it in some hacky way - I just changed `sql.DB` mock to return `Tx interface` instead of final type, and tested against it, but now it needs to integrate test into production code.

I don’t want to make some wrappers on `sql.DB` in production code just to make unit tests working, but what are other solutions???

And *why* is it a standard in Go to return types instead of interfaces?
It makes testing harder!

Comment: At the moment I see 3 possible solutions here:  
1. Create a wrapper over sql.DB
`type myDB struct {
 db *sql.DB
}`
and change all original calls to this wrapper. Wrapper is satisfied with the ITX interface. so it's easy to generate mock and do all needed tests.  
2. Another option - using something like sqlmock. It's a 3rd party driver designed for mock testing. It already has methods to control transaction calls.  
3. I got from Senior Go developer - don't use unit tests here (I'm still not clear about it) - just start real database and check your data actually persisted there.

Answer (score 0):

Dependency injection is the way to go.

`sql.BeginTx` returns a concrete type, but everywhere you pass the transaction, you should depend on a transaction interface rather than the type.

e.g.

```
type Transaction interface {
    Commit() error
    Exec(query string, args ...any) (sql.Result, error)
}
```

Now you can inject a mock transaction rather than the real `sql.Tx` anywhere as long as your mock satisfies the same type.
For testing, your mock could then record calls to the transaction which you can verify.

Comment: The main problem here - that I'm ready to depend on the interface versus final type but it's a Go's stdlib code I'm trying to test. sql.DB contains method BeginTx which returns sql.Tx, so it's not possible to use and interfaces here, and provide a mock. I tried to look deeply into reflect. package but with no luck. Figured out 3 possible solutions here. I will explain below.

Comment: It sounds like your problem is that you are calling `BeginTX` inside the method that you need to use it, rather than calling it in an outer function, and then passing it in ?

If you do the latter, then you can pass in a mock instead.

Comment: Yes this is a good catch! It's a kind of transaction manager I wrote. But now I don't see any good way to test it :)

Comment: Do you have a link to the repo perhaps?